# groovy null safe operator, identifying what was null?

Tags: groovy

The null safe operator in Groovy is great for reducing code and making things more readable. We can go from this:

```
def customer = getCustomer(custNo)
if(!customer)
   throw new Exception("Invalid customer: ${custNo}")

def policy = customer.getPolicy(policyNo)
if(!policy)
   throw new Exception("Invalid policy: ${policyNo}")

def claim = policy.getClaim(claimNo)
if(!claim)
   throw new Exception("Invalid claim: ${claimNo}")
```

..to this...

```
def claim = getCustomer(custNo)?.getPolicy(policyNo)?.getClaim(claimNo)
```

But nothing's for free; using null/safe navigation, if `claim` is null, it's not immediately obvious *what* caused it: either `custNo`, `policyNo`, or `claimNo` may be invalid.

We could go back and start checking what's null, but that's counterproductive, and actually, it's not even possible since intermediate objects are not stored in variables.

So the question is: **Is it possible to identify what was null when chaining method calls using null/safe navigation?**

### UPDATE

I took another stab at this using [dynamic method invocation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Dynamic+Groovy). It takes an init target (usually a dao) to initialize the object (customer in this case), and a map containing method names as strings (with arguments as values). Using an iterator, `invokeChain` simply traverses the map (chain); if anything in the chain returns null, identifying the method that caused it becomes trivial.

```
  def invokeChain = { initTarget, chain ->
     def obj
     chain.eachWithIndex{ it, idx ->
        //init obj from dao on first iteration only,
        //remaining iterations get from obj itself
        obj = (!idx) ? initTarget."$it.key"(it.value) : obj?."$it.key"(it.value)            

        if(!obj)
           throw new Exception("${it.key}(${it.value}) returned null")           
     }
     obj
  }
```

#### Usage

Mock a `customer` dao for `initTarget`...I've inserted `null` as return type for `getClaim()`, which should throw an exception.

```
   def static getCustomer = { custNo ->
      [ getPolicy: { p ->           
            [getClaim:{ c ->
                  null //"Claim #${c}"
               }]
         }]
   }
```

..using `invokeChain`, easy as pie:

```
  def claim = invokeChain(this, [getCustomer:123, getPolicy:456, getClaim:789])
```

...throws exception, as expected:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: getClaim(789) returned null
```

I like this approach because it's compact, readable, and easy to use; what do you think?

Comment: I provided a working interception example, and slightly extended an answer. Thanks for interesting stimulus for investigation.

Comment: Yes, that solution is pretty good. It is not intercepting in ?. syntax, and need some changes in existing code. What I can notice, that map order can potentially change method calls, but as Groovy uses LinkedHashMap by default - there is seems to be good. Also I trying to play with MOP, just for fun, and if I have get good results will post it here. Sorry for late comment, I was somewhat busy.

Answer (score 4):

I think there is no clear way to do so.
I can be wrong, will check sources later, but safe navigation is a syntax sugar for if statement.

As a hack you can wrap your code with [interceptor](http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN3515-Interception), trace last method call inside, and then use that info to proide error message.

It will not be cheap, and will cost you some code to realize interception and some performance while running. But you can achieve something like

```
    mayFail("getCusomer", "getPolicy", "getClaim") {
         getCustomer(custNo)?.getPolicy(policyNo)?.getClaim(claimNo)
    } == "getPolicy" // failed on second step
```

**EDIT:** As **@tim_yates** proved, `?.` is a syntax sugar with if construction behind. Thanks **Vorg van Geir** for the link, I have [copied](http://groovy.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Interceptors) it here, to an answer. He say, it's outdated, and it looks like he is right. I have managed to make ProxyMetaClass work(in Groovy 2.0.6), so given way isn't totally broken. Now I need to specify exact classes to intercept, and I can not find a way to catch inherited method calls.(to simply intercept `java.lang.Object`)

```
def logInterceptor = new TracingInterceptor()
logInterceptor.writer = new StringWriter()

def intProxy = ProxyMetaClass.getInstance(Integer)
def stringProxy = ProxyMetaClass.getInstance(String)
intProxy.setInterceptor(logInterceptor)
stringProxy.setInterceptor(logInterceptor)
intProxy.use {
    stringProxy.use {
       println(("Hello" + "world").size().hashCode())
}   }

println(logInterceptor.writer.toString())
```

All that hell may be wrapped in some utility code, but I highly doubt in necessarity of this. Performance overhead will be awful and some boilerplate code will remain.

The game is not worth the candle.

Comment: Or just use the old style `if( customer != null ) { policy = customer.getPolicy( policyNo ).......`

Comment: @tim_yates isn't old style the thing, OP wants to avoid?

Comment: yeah, but the `?.` operator is syntactic sugar, not magic ;-)

Comment: > "As a hack you can wrap your code with interceptor"... The code on that Codehaus page is for Groovy 1.5, and mostly no longer works (many features get added to Groovy but only remain tested for a single version, then quietly forgotten about). I reposted [the corrected doco for Groovy 1.7 elsewhere](http://groovy.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Interceptors) but again even that one's probably out of date.

Comment: @VorgvanGeir Thanks for constructive feedback. I extended an answer, and include your link there.

Comment: @Seagull this is interesting, gave me some ideas, but you're right, this approach is not worth it; too much work; I've added my solution to the question, let me know what you think, thx!

Comment: @tim _"quietly forgotten about"_ is putting it nicely.

Answer (score 3):

What about attributions and asserts?

```
def policy = customer?.policy
def claim = policy?.claim
def number = claim?.number

assert customer, "Invalid customer"
assert policy, 'Invalid policy'
assert claim, 'Invalid claim'
```

---

**UPDATE:**

You already found the solution, but i'd like to contribute with an interceptor idea:

The mock:

```
def dao = [
  getCustomer : { custNo ->
    [ getPolicy: { p ->           
      [getClaim:{ c ->
          null //"Claim #${c}"
      }]
    }]
  }
]
```

The interceptor:

```
class MethodCallInterceptor {
  def delegate
  def invokeMethod(String method, args) {
    def result = delegate.invokeMethod(method, args)
    if (result == null) {
      throw new RuntimeException("$method returned null")
    }
    else {
      new MethodCallInterceptor(delegate: result)
    }
  }

  def getProperty(String property ) { 
    delegate[ property ]
  }

  void setProperty(String property, value) {
    delegate[ property ] = value
  }
}
```

The test:

```
def interceptedDao = new MethodCallInterceptor(delegate: dao)

try {
  interceptedDao.getCustomer(123).getPolicy(456).getClaim(789)
  assert false
} catch (e) {
  assert e.message.contains( 'getClaim returned null' )
}
```

Comment: The issue with this is `assert` for each element in the chain, which must be added manually; I've added my solution that addresses this, see above.

Comment: I thought you wanted to address a single issue, not a generic solution. Interesting solution. I'm thinking about a decorator, but i guess the result would be more or less the same

Comment: @raffian, i suggested an interceptor idea :-)

Comment: Thanks, Will, we're thinking along the same lines, either way works nicely, and generically, which is important to me, should have mentioned that earlier.